# Moving a slide show to the left in html

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow

In my website I added a slide show and it works. However my slideshow is on the left side and I want to be able to  move the whole slideshow over so it's in the spot I want it to be. How do I do this?? I put the code for only the slideshow in the bottom. I have been using Html and Css.

```
<div class="SlideShow" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Image1.jpg" style="width:100%"/>
  <img class="mySlides" src="Image2.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <a class="display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>


<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}

</script>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.slider-holder
        {
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .image-holder
        {
            width: 2400px;
            background-color: red;
            height: 400px;
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            
            -webkit-transition: left 2s;
            -moz-transition: left 2s;
            -o-transition: left 2s;
            transition: left 2s;
        }
        
        .slider-image
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: 0px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -800px;
        }
        
        #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -1600px;
        }
        
        .button-holder
        {
            position: relative;
            top: -20px;
        }
        
        .slider-change
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: brown;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slider-holder">
        <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
        <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
        <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/2.jpg" class="slider-image" />
            <img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/3.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
            <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
            <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
#outerbox{
 width:700px;
 overflow:hidden;
 
 }
#sliderbox{
 position:relative;
 width:2800px;
 animation:animation 20s infinite;
 
 }
#sliderbox img{
 float:left;
 } 
@keyframes animation{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  }
 100%{
  left:-2800px; 
   }
  }
```

```html
<div id="outerbox">
<div id="sliderbox">
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg"/> 
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/2.jpg"/>
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/3.jpg"/>
```

Comment: How would I move the second slideshow to the right a bit?